# Xcode : Included extra .h and .c files for the linking of code

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have a simple project in XCode and I am using C++ as the target project. 
So I created a main.cpp that has the main function. 
Now I wanted to create objects on other files. I keep getting a Linking error. 
I am unable to locate the place where this needs to be changed. 
main.cpp code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fruits/FruitA.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   // insert code here...
   std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
   createFruitA();
   return 0;
}
```

Now have these files in FruitsA.h and FruitsA.c

```
#ifndef FruitA_h
#define FruitA_h

#include <stdio.h>

int createFruitA();

#endif /* FruitA_h */
```

and FruitA.c

```
#include "FruitA.h"

int createFruitA()
{
    printf("I am FruitA\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is structured in Xcode as follows [image: Structure of Code organized in Xcode]

I know that we have to add the FruitsA.c for linkage but am unsure as to where it is!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "createFruitA()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please don't name your C++ source files `.c`. I don't know about Xcode, but some IDE assume the language based on the file ending and `.c` stands for C, not C++. Use `.cpp` for C++ source files as you did for `main.cpp`. It may actually solve your current problem as well. In any case it is confusing to name the file wrong. Also don't use `printf` in C++ code, use `std::cout` as you did in `main.cpp`. Finally move the `#include <stdio.h>` into the source file. You are using `printf` in the source file, not in the header file. Put headers where they are used.

Comment: On the off-chance that you intend the second source file to be compiled as C rather than C++: 1. Do you really need that? 2. Cross-language linking doesn't quite work like that. You need to tell C++ that the function is a C function using `export "C"` in the declaration in the header and you need to guard that with a preprocessor conditional based on whether or not `__cplusplus` is defined (i.e. whether compilation of the header is for C or C++)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried with making the entire code in C++ and it builds properly.